# How to create Service Principal of Multi-tenant Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I have created new Azure AAD Application with Multi-tenant enabled. But i Couldn't find App in another tenant ID. When i try to create a Service Principal of above App ID in another Tenant.It is failing with error ***"New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal : When using this permission, the backing application of the service principal being created must in the local tenant"*** . Has anyone experience such issue.

```
$StartDate = [DateTime]::UtcNow                                                                
$EndDate = [DateTime]::UtcNow.AddYears(3)                                                 
$secureString = convertto-securestring "XXXXXXXXX" -asplaintext -force                             
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "XXXXXXXXXX" -Password $secureString -StartDate $StartDate -EndDate $EndDate
```

Comment: Hmm, I've actually never tried this. I feel that this might require a user from that tenant to consent to the permissions interactively..

Comment: Hi, do you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my question using following PS command

```bsh
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId '<TargetTenant>'                                            

New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId 'ThirdPartyAppID'
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce this error. `New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "XXXXXXXXXX"` works fine for me to create the enterprise app in another tenant.

If you want to add the multi-tenant app into another tenant, there is another way. You can have a try with the [admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin).

I assume that your app is registered in tenant_x and want to add it into tenant_y.

You can redirect the user to the Microsoft identity platform admin consent endpoint.

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_y}/v2.0/adminconsent?
  client_id={client id}
  &state=12345
  &redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
    &scope=
    https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.read 
    https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send
```

Access it in a broswer and log in with an admin account of tenant_y to do the admin consent. After that the app will be added into tenant_y.

Comment: I fixed this issue in a different way.Thanks for your answer                                                                                   Connect-AzureAD -TenantId '<TargetTenant>''                                                                      New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId 'ThirdPartyAppID'

Comment: This URL is what worked for me. I provided my scope URL instead of graph URL